# Using acetone instead of acetonitrile on reverse-phase prep-HPLC

Tags: green-chemistry

I've been using reverse phase prep-HPLC a LOT lately, and I'm growing increasingly concerned about the amount of acetonitrile needed. In an attempt to use a cheaper and more environmentally friendly solvent I had a read around and discovered you can substitute MeCN with acetone.

Has anyone ever tried this? How did it compare in a broad sense?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go completely green, you should use ethanol. 
In many sectors it is considered the only green solvent (except for water of course). 
Then, to be really green, you should make sure that it comes from fermentation, not from synthesis. 
This quality exists.

The only problem with ethanol is the same as with acetonitrile, the price. 
In this case it is due to the taxes that it normally has. 
However, if you are working for some institution, it is probable that you can buy it tax free.

Another alternative is to use methanol. 
It is not so green, but you can call it wood alcohol.
Methanol works very well in HPLC. 
The only difference with acetonitrile is that the pressure in the system will be higher. 
This is normally not a problem because the equipment is designed for it.

I prefer not to use acetone because it can give reaction with some compounds, or with itself to form isophorone or other condensation products. 
As Waylander correctly points out in his comment, the UV cut off of acetone is also a problem in case you are using UV detection.

```
                 UV cut off (nm)
 acetonitrile        190
 methanol            205
 ethanol             210
 acetone             330
```

To change from one solvent to another you will have to change the gradient.

Comment: You will also need to look at your detection system. If you are using UV then be aware that acetone absorbs across a different range than MeCN

Comment: @Waylander Very true. Thank you for the hint. I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - reports are easily located using a search engine and keywords such as "HPLC", "acetone", "green chemistry", and "acetonitrile":

One abstract [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/rcm.4352/abstract):

*The use of acetone as a substitute for acetonitrile in analysis of peptides by liquid chromatography/electrospray ionization mass spectrometry*. Keppel et al. Rapid Comm. Mass Spect. December 2, 2009.

and another write-up (non-refereed):

[HPLC going green: Generic replacement of acetonitrile with acetone](http://www.separationsnow.com/details/ezine/14e071a8ac5/HPLC-going-green-Generic-replacement-of-acetonitrile-with-acetone.html?tzcheck=1,1,1,1&)

and another abstract [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jssc.201401324/abstract):

*Acetone as a greener alternative to acetonitrile in liquid chromatographic fingerprinting*. Funari et al. J. Separation Science. April 2, 2015.

Comparisons are favorable and generally require modest changes in what to expect in terms of retention times and peak broadening.